# Image increase together the page zooming (ctrl +)

Tags: html, css

I need increase an image using ctrl +, using `style: width: 100%;` in css.

```
<div style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid black;">
    <img src="../images/userInterface/SP255.png" width=93% style="margin-left: 3.5%; margin-top: 20px;"/>    <!-- sp255 tem 1250px -->  
</div>
```

if i use width: 1000px for example, the image is increasing together the page zoom, but, if i using width: 95%; the image don't increase.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: how to increase the image together the browser zoom (ctrl +), using width as percentual

Comment: I'm guessing this is the way browsers zoom elements - if it has a fixed width, then it will zoom accordingly, if it is a percentage, then it will zoom responsively which may not look like it is zooming

Comment: oh, its is true! but i need to know if has a any way to make it

Comment: I don't think you can with a percentage - it will always resize as it is a percentage so you need to have a fixed width if you want the zooming to be the same, otherwise you would need a js plugin of some sort - see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51455182/image-size-not-increasing-on-browser-zoom

Answer (score 1):

You have your `div` set to 100%, so as you zoom in the image increases width, but the containing div at `width: 100%` prevents it from passing screen width.

Remove the `width` from your div.

```html
<div style="border: 1px solid black;">
    <img src="https://www.placecage.com/1000/1000" width=93% style="margin-left: 3.5%; margin-top: 20px;"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you follow the below code.. I tested myself.. it's working

**HTML**

```
<div style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid black;">
    <img src="../images/userInterface/SP255.png" style="max-width:93%; margin-left: 3.5%; margin-top: 20px;"/>    <!-- sp255 tem 1250px -->
</div>
```